# Inserting default string if None is value in dictionary

Tags: python

I am looping through a list of dictionaries and cleaning the text to get rid of `<h2>` tags, commas etc so that when the values are put into pandas dataframe they will just show text:

Here is the function as of now:

```
def first_clean(my_dict):
    my_dict = {k: v[0] for k, v in my_dict.items()}
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        if '<h2>' in v:
            my_dict[k] = v.replace('<h2>', '').replace('</h2>', '')
    print(my_dict)


first_clean({'Name': ['<h2>person name</h2>'], 'Phone': ['(205) ***-****'], 'Website': ['https://www.*****/company-profile'], 'Email': [
    'sp5576@s******'], 'Address': ['address'], 'State': ['AL']})
```

This works fine until one of the values is `None` at which point it throws:
`TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`

I have tried adding if statements to the function such as:

```
def first_clean(my_dict):
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        if v is None:
            v = "default"
        my_dict = {k: v[0] for k, v in my_dict.items()}
        for k, v in my_dict.items():
            if '<h2>' in v:
                my_dict[k] = v.replace('<h2>', '').replace('</h2>', '')
        print(my_dict)
```

which still returns the same error. I can't find what I need to change at this point. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't `{k: v[0] for k, v in my_dict.items() if v}` do it?

Comment: Can you give an exmaple of the sample data with a "none" value that you speak off.

Comment: I just tried that and it returned the same error. I previously had tried ```{k: v[0] for k, v in my_dict.items() if v is not None}``` and other variations but for some reason it still returns the error once it reaches `if '<h2>' in v:`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle ```{'Name': [None], 'Phone': ['(205) ***-****'], 'Website': ['https://www.*****/company-profile'], 'Email': [
    'sp5576@s******'], 'Address': ['address'], 'State': ['AL']}``` This would be one example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just try this approach:

```
my_dict = {k: v[0] if v is not None else "" for k, v in my_dict.items()}
```

The output of this:

```
def first_clean(my_dict):
    my_dict = {k: v[0] if v is not None else "" for k, v in my_dict.items()}
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        if '<h2>' in v:
            my_dict[k] = v.replace('<h2>', '').replace('</h2>', '')
    print(my_dict)


first_clean({'Name': ['<h2>person name</h2>'], 'Phone': ['(205) ***-****'], 'Website': ['https://www.*****/company-profile'], 'Email': ['sp5576@s******'], 'Address': ['address'], 'State': None})
```

is:

```
{'Name': 'person name', 'Phone': '(205) ***-****', 'Website': 'https://www.*****/company-profile', 'Email': 'sp5576@s******', 'Address': 'address', 'State': ''}
```

Comment: Yes I like how concise this is as well as being able to input something else in its place. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change the `if` statement to only check if the value is not `None`.

```
def first_clean(my_dict):
    my_dict = {k: v[0] for k, v in my_dict.items()}
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        if v and '<h2>' in v:
            my_dict[k] = v.replace('<h2>', '').replace('</h2>', '')
    print(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if v is not none and then look for H2 in v

```py
def first_clean(my_dict):
    my_dict = {k: v[0] for k, v in my_dict.items()}
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        if v is not None and '<h2>' in v:
            my_dict[k] = v.replace('<h2>', '').replace('</h2>', '')
    print(my_dict)


first_clean({'Name': [None], 'Phone': ['(205) ***-****'], 'Website': ['https://www.*****/company-profile'], 'Email': [     'sp5576@s******'], 'Address': ['address'], 'State': ['AL']} )
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'Name': None, 'Phone': '(205) ***-****', 'Website': 'https://www.*****/company-profile', 'Email': 'sp5576@s******', 'Address': 'address', 'State': 'AL'}
```

Comment: Yes a None value as opposed to empty list. Thank you this worked! I was thinking I needed to test for it before the for loop instead of inside it. Thanks!